# Converting special characters to regular c#

Tags: c#

Is there a command in C# to convert strings like : `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com` back to `https://www.google.com`?

some sort of "decryption" method maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode` for this:

```
string real = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedString);
```

You can use the reverse function `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to encode.

This is not a matter of encryption or decryption. It is just that some characters cannot be expressed as part of parameters or other in a URL. For instance, a colon (:) cannot be part of a URL tail because it is used in the prefix (http:), so it gets encoded as %3A.

In the same way, a slash gets encoded as %2F. Hence, %3A%2F2%F means ://.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
```

or

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not working on a web application, I suggest you use the [WebUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx) class instead as you don't have to import the entire System.Web assembly to access `UrlDecode`, which is required for the `HttpUtility` class. (You'll need to be targeting .NET 4)

```
string unencoded = WebUtility.UrlDecode("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com");
```

You can also use `Uri.UnescapeDataString` if don't require any other `HTML` encoding/decoding methods. This is `System.Uri` so you don't need to import any other assembly.